# xtgmath.h has compile-time errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to compile an older C++ program in Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I am encountering a compile error, with Visual Studio saying that there are syntax errors in the `xtgmath.h` file. The complete log is:

> 1>  fill.cpp 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): error C2059: syntax error : '('
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::enable_if'
>
> 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtr1common(67) : see declaration of 'std::enable_if'
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): warning C4346: 'std::is_integral<_Ty>::value' : dependent name is not a type
>
> 1>          prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ','
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): error C2059: syntax error : ','
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(179): error C2059: syntax error : ')'

I have tried several different things that others have recommended, but none of it seems to work. I tried to run the preprocessor over the source file and examine the generated code, but it offered no insights. Does anyone have an idea about what's going wrong here?

Comment: My guess is a macro breaking things.

Comment: And this is why Microsoft was reluctant to support C99, lots of common short words dumped in the global namespace.  But they had to, C++11 demands it.  You'll have to chase down `cbrt`.  Write your macros in all-capitals to avoid this kind of lossage.

Answer (score 0):

I was have the exact same error as you -- working with old code and now trying to compile it under VS2013. For me the problem was tied to this line of xtgmath.h:

> _GENERIC_MATH1(**round**, _CRTSPECIAL)

I nailed it down to **round** being predefined in stdafx.h.  In VS2013, **round** is already a built in function and having the definition override caused the compile errors.

To solve this I have commented out the **round** definition in stdafx.h.

Comment: You can easily tell from the line number in the error message that it isn't *round* that causes this.

Comment: Agreed but issue may be similar to mine where cbrt function has been defined elsewhere